# How to display breadcrumbs on Magento Sitemap

Tags: magento, sitemap, breadcrumbs

Is there a way to get breadcrumbs to appear on the top of my sitemap page?

I want my breadcrumbs to display on ALL pages, and these are the only pages I can't get them to display on.

I added this to the top of the display container file and its not working... Any ideas?

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs")->toHtml()?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need also add actual crumbs to the list by calling `addCrumb()` function. It is defined in  [Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Page/Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs.html) class. You can achieve like this:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs")->
              ->addCrumb('CrumbName', array('label' => 'this will appear as link text', 'title' => 'title attribute of link', 'link' => 'url to the page')
              ->toHtml()
?>
```

You can also do this in xml config file. In catalog.xml `catalog_seo_sitemap` handler do the following changes:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>breadcrumbs</alias></action>
    <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">        
      <action method="addCrumb"><crumbName>Name</crumbName><crumbInfo><label>Test</label><title>Test</title><link>/test.html</link></crumbInfo></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```